# How to call python file in a feature file of karate automation?

Tags: automation, karate

I need to call a .py file and pass an argument to one of the functions in it and have to match the result returned.

For instance:
xyz.py

KarateXyz.feature

- match result == call('xyz.py')# how to specify the method name and pass an argument in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `karate.exec()` to call any OS process. Whether python is installed is up to you. Refer https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-exec

```
* def result = karate.exec('python foo.py bar')
```

For more details, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64352676/143475

Comment: Yes the code works * def result = karate.exec('python xyz.py') but I need to return a list from the method in that .py file when invoked from feature file. How to do that?